# How to add local users to a site collection in sharepoint2013, while server is in Workgroup

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-accounts

I have installed Sharepoint2013 on a local server. i.e Server is in Workgroup. Server is not in Domain. I have created on root site collection, and trying to add users from Site

Settings>Peoples and Groups>Site Permissions> Add users.

But I could not find any users to add.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not a supported scenario for a production system.  SharePoint is specifically designed to run in a domain environment.  "Things" will not work all over the place if only a workgroup and local accounts are used (in your case, the People Picker, which only works with domains).

Answer (score 1):

One way to interpret your question is that you are attempting to add local users and groups to your SharePoint 2010,2013 Farm's site. One may want to do this if they are creating an isolated sharepoint farm accessible by extranet users and do not want to use a.d., live or ADFS accounts.

I was able to get the local users and groups to add by executing the following steps in and admin prompt of SharePoint PowerShell.
1) You must password enable the people picker
Stsadm.exe –o setapppassword –password 
2) Setting a default group will tell SharePoint to tie the local groups and users into the SharePoint Farm
- site -> site settings -> people and groups -> Select group to make default -> settings -> Make default group
3) attempt to add the group or user to a site using people picker
- i.e. servername\. 
- The group may not be found right away, but you have now told SharePoint to look locally

### Troubleshooting:

1) It may take anywhere from 2-4 hours depending upon application pools to recycle for the above changes to take effect. So be patient, grab lunch and upon return try adding the groups or users multiple times in people picker if they do not resolve.

2) Check the registry key permissions for full control regarding the local groups wss_admin_wpg and wss_wpg.
HKLM > Software > Microsoft > Shared Tools > Web Server Extensions > 14.0 or your version number of the hive > Secure

Answer (score 0):

Join the server to the domain where your Active Directory users are, or a domain where you can connect to the Active Directory via an ADFS connection.

Comment: Hi Benny, thank you for your reply.. but we don't need Active directory users.. we only need local server users to add

Comment: OK. What happens if you add the Farm account (as test)?

Comment: I can able to add account in Configure Managed Accounts, but while trying to add user in Site Collection level, I'm unable to add new user(Site Settings>People and Groups>Site Permissions>New>Add new user). I could not find users in that tab

Answer (score 0):

**PowerShell:**

```
Get-SPWeb 'http://mysp13:1234/' | New-SPUser -UserAlias 'mysp13\PoupkineVV' -DisplayName 'Puopkin Vassily'
```

After that you can add user as `mysp13\PoupkineVV` in people picker.